# Why did NASA need to observationally confirm whether DART successfully redirected Dimorphos?

Tags: momentum, orbital-motion, collision, asteroids

NASA's DART impactor made a head-on collision with the asteroid Dimorphos on September 26, 2022. A real-time video feed gave immediate confirmation of the direct hit. But according to [this press release](https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-confirms-dart-mission-impact-changed-asteroid-s-motion-in-space), NASA had to observe Dimorphos for two more weeks before being able to confirm that Dimorphos's trajectory was indeed noticeably altered (as planned).

Why? It seems to me that determining the collision's effect on Dimorphos's orbit would be a very simple exercise in Newtonian mechanics. I assume that Dimorphos's total mass was well-known from its orbital dynamics with Didymos. I know that its internal composition wasn't well understood, but is that really so important for understanding its post-collision dynamics? Conservation of momentum means that the subsequent overall motion of Dimorphos's center of mass should not be affected by the details of its internal composition.

I know that the collision ejected some material off of Dimorphos's surface, so there's a bit of a semantic question as to whether after the collision, the term "Dimorphos" should refer to "all of that material that made up Dimorphos *before* the collision" or "what's left on the largest connected component of that material *after* the collision". But it doesn't seem to me that this would make a big difference regarding Dimorphos's overall dynamics. It seems to me that approximating the collision as a perfectly inelastic collision between two point particles would probably give a pretty good model. Even if the impactor did knock off a significant fraction of Dimorphos's mass (which seems unlikely), then it seems to me that this outcome would count as "significantly changing its trajectory" almost by definition.

Was there ever really any genuine uncertainty whether DART would redirect Dimorphos *given that* DART directly impacted Dimorphos? What kind of plausible internal composition of Dimorphos could have led to a failure to be redirected?

**Edit to clarify question scope:** As is often the case, many people are interpreting the title of my question too literally. (My understanding is that Stack Exchange's convention is that the "official" version of an SE question is found in the question body, and the purpose of the question's title is to draw attention rather to precisely state the question.) I'm not trying to have a general philosophical debate about how much you should trust theory vs. experiment. Nor am I trying to understand why NASA actually *did* observationally confirm the redirection, as a lot of complicated non-physics factors enter into that decision. (So any speculation about NASA's political incentives, etc. are out of scope for this question.) I'm just asking, very concretely, what were the main sources of scientific uncertainty in the extent to which Dimorphos would be redirected given a successful collision, and how those uncertainties would affect the extent of redirection. "The composition of Dimorphos" would not be a concrete enough uncertainty; I'd like to know *how* the composition of Dimorphos would change the redirection. Of the many comments and answer to this question so far, only John Doty's answer addresses my question within the scope that I intended it.

Comment: Seems like a better fit for [space.se] but offhand what's wrong with good old fashioned needing to scientifically verify an experimental result as many ways as possible ?

Comment: Article on DART: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/PSJ/ac063e

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine It's a perfectly good physics question. Real physics: energy, momentum, and experiment out in the real world.

Comment: In a more fundamental sense, the scientific method requires that all hypotheses should be verified by observation and/or experimental results.  In other words, if the observation or experimental results don't match up with predictions, the predictions either need to be modified or rejected.

Comment: @DavidWhite Okay, sure. But my question was really whether there was genuine scientific uncertainty as to how much the asteroid would be deflected, assuming *very* well-accepted theories like the validity of Newtonian mechanics in the appropriate physical regimes.

Comment: @tparker, you may well be making the hidden assumption that all the important variables are known to a high degree of certainty.  While that may be true, there is no way to know that without performing the experiment and accurately measuring the results.

Comment: Or let's look at it this way: you spend over 300 million $ to launch a probe which will impact an asteroid, and then you don't bother to spend a bit more money to check if the impact actually changed the asteroid's trajectory by the amount you expected? I mean, if all the variables were already known beforehand, you could have simulated the whole thing for a lot less money?

Comment: @DavidWhite No, I'm not making that assumption. The entire point of my question is asking which are the most important variables that contribute to the uncertainty and why.

Comment: @rob74 I'm not asking why NASA made the effort to observe whether DART redirected Dimorphos. I'm asking whether there was genuine scientific uncertainty in what they'd find, given that DART had made a direct hit. Also, I had believed (perhaps incorrectly) that the main scientific question being tested was whether DART could hit the asteroid at all, which could not be answered via simulations.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine well, it seems awfully expensive just to test Netwon’s Law, so I kind of hope they had good reason.

Comment: @tparker: NASA set the success criterium for DART at a change in orbital period of 73 seconds or more. The fact that they set a success criterium at all seems to indicate that there was, in fact, uncertainty. The fact that they were off by a factor of 25, more than an order of magnitude seems to indicate the uncertainty was not insignificant.

Comment: I have a non-physics answer.  There may be future projects to redirect asteroids, that require financial backing from organisations other than the United States Government.  Suppose I'm the CEO of a business that's contemplating donating $100m to such a project, in the hope of preventing a collision or near-collision between an asteroid and Earth.  I'd kind of like to see some evidence that NASA is actually able to change the course of asteroids, before committing the funds.   Show me some pretty diagrams or videos of what happened with Dimorphos and I'll get out my cheque book.

Comment: The simple answer to your question is: your back-of-envelope estimation of the estimates involved is way off.

Comment: There is uncertainty. But you don't know how far reality deviates from your best guess, so you measure.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'm not sure I agree. Even if you're very confident in what will happen, you still need to define some concrete cutoff for mission success. Was NASA really setting its threshold for success near the expected level of deflection? That could have deliberately been a very conservative threshold.

Comment: @JörgWMittag It seems plausible to me that NASA set that threshold in order to adjudicate the event of a very glancing impact by DART rather than a direct hit - which (I believe) *was* a very realistic possibility.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The spacecraft had a large amount of energy, but not a lot of momentum. Most of the impulse delivered to the target was due to the momentum of the ejecta. Energy scales as $mv^2$, but momentum scales as $mv$. For a given energy, cut the ejecta velocity in half, eject four times as much, and deliver twice the impulse. But whether the energy produces a small quantity of fast ejecta or a large quantity of slow ejecta depends the the material properties of the target. These were poorly known.

Comment: You’re saying that if Dimorphos had been a completely rigid body, then the DART impact would not have detectably changed its orbit? That’s very surprising to me.

Comment: @tparker Detectably? Sure. But NASA wanted a bigger effect.

Comment: Or (I believe) equivalently, you’re saying that the orbit of the center of mass of all the material that originally comprised Dimorphos before the collision (but not including DART) did not noticeably deviate from Dimorphos’s original orbit (at least neglecting gravitational interaction effects with Didymos)?

Comment: @tparker The momentum 
of DART+Dimorphos immediately before the collision was essentially the same as the momentum of DART+Dimorphos+ejecta immediately after. But DART wasn't in orbit about Didymos, and probably most of the ejecta wasn't either, so you can't talk about *the* orbit of all the stuff.

Comment: Do have a citation for the claim that "Most of the impulse delivered to the target was due to the momentum of the ejecta."? That's quite surprising to me, and I'd be interested to learn more.

Comment: @tparker - (note: not previous commenter) "most" is an exaggeration, but just working things out as though they were elastic gives ~15m change in orbital period (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/731677/dart-crash-on-dimorphos-computation-of-orbital-period-change) but the actual crash changed orbital period by ~32 minutes (https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-confirms-dart-mission-impact-changed-asteroid-s-motion-in-space)

Comment: @tparker Just look at the numbers again. NASA expected 18min orbit shortening, they got 32min. That's almost twice as much speed change as anticipated. I'm pretty sure that the expected 18min included the entire spacecraft momentum plus some expected ejecta effect. As such, `14/32 = 43%` of the effect must have been due to *unexpected* ejecta effects. Add in the expected ejecta effects, and you can be pretty certain that the ejecta effects dominated.

Comment: was _"due to"_ or _"composed of"_ the momentum of the ejecta? Since ejecta is what results from the impact, not what delivers the impact.

Comment: If you hit the asteroid on the side, you could make it rotate. Which wouldn't change its speed or direction at all. (I wouldn't say _unexpected_ effects but _unpredictable_ effects. They were probably quite sure that 18mins is the best guess, but unlikely to be accurate).

Comment: @gnasher729 As long as DART gets absorbed into the asteroid rather than deflecting off of it, it will tranfer momentum into the asteroid and certainly change its speed and direction (in additional to possibly changing its rotation).

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica Do you have a citation that NASA expected 18 minutes? Or are you just going off of the other Stack Exchange answer? I am not confident that an SE answer would accurate capture NASA's expectations.

Comment: @JohnDoty I take your point, but the actual redirection was *25 times* NASA's threshold for a successful redirection. Do you have a sense of whether the composition of Dimorphos was *so* uncertain that NASA was truly unsure (say, <99% confident) that they would surpass that threshold, conditioned on a direct hit by DART?

Comment: @tparker Indeed, I didn't bother looking up that number since the other poster already gave it. I did, however, previously hear from independent and typically knowledgeable sources that the effect was almost twice as large as predicted. And that the actual period change was about half an hour. The numbers of the other answer fit into that background knowledge rather nicely, so I had little reason to suspect that they might be off. If you don't trust these numbers, why don't you invest some time into chasing them down yourself?

Answer (score 15):

Because sometimes things don't quite turn out as the theory expects, and the only way to know is to experiment.

Aa an example, take the main result of this experiment: the orbital period was changed by ~32min (https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-confirms-dart-mission-impact-changed-asteroid-s-motion-in-space).

If we take for correct the calculations in [DART crash on Dimorphos: computation of orbital period change](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/731677/dart-crash-on-dimorphos-computation-of-orbital-period-change) and we add to that an estimate of the effect due to reshaping outlined in https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/PSJ/ac7566, taking the larger estimates, we arrive at a change of 18 minutes, well short of the real world 32.

I'm no physicist and I haven't read all the details of either calculation, so there may well be some assumption made both times that could be integrated (there probably is), but I think it well shows how much value there is in actually preforming the experiment and not trusting theory blindly.

Answer (score 2):

Biliards or snooker are games where you can perfectly calculate the mechanics, nonetheless there is still a great amount of variability.

In the case of DART the impact point might have been solid rock or rubble slipping sideways and dispersing part of the momentum or something in between. Another factor of uncertainty is the angle, it is very difficult to hit with great precision a rotating body.

Comment: Neither of your suggestions (v1) can carry linear momentum out of the asteroid+spacecraft system.

Comment: Even for billiards or snooker, you cannot do the calculations without doing some measurements first: 1) How inelastic are collisions actually? 2) How high is the friction between the velt and a sliding ball? 3) How high is the drag of a rolling ball? 4) How high is the friction between colliding balls (angular momentum transfer!)? 5) How high is the friction between the queue and the ball with varying amounts of chalk in between? And that's even before you start trying to pin down the precise starting position, queue velocity/momentum and point of contact between queue and ball...

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-00601-4) confirms John Doty's answer that the biggest unknown was indeed how much ejecta the DART impact would throw out from Dimorphos:

> Researchers estimate that this spray of rubble meant Dimorphos’ added momentum was almost four times that imparted by DART.

My take is that strictly speaking - putting aside epistemological questions about the nature of proof - it wasn't really necessary for NASA to observe the aftermath of the collision in order to determine *whether* DART significantly modified Dimorphos's trajectory; that would have happened even for a completely inelastic (head-on) collision with no ejecta at all. But NASA did need to observe the aftermath in order to determine by *how much* the impact changed Dimorphos's trajectory.